# ILogger does not write to console using serilog

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I'm trying to use serligo as my main logging utilitie but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

In the `Program.cs` file, I configure the logger and also log a startup message, **this message gets outputted to the console**.

I also have, in one of my controllers, an `ILogger<HomeController>` instance that logs information when a certain action is called. **These logs are not outputted to the console**, and I cannot understand why.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        try
        {
            Log.Information("Starting up version {version}", Defaults.Version); // WORKS
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Fatal(ex, "Application start-up failed");
        }
        finally
        {
            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Home/Index"); //Does not work
        return View();
    }
 
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Error"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.RenderedCompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))

The issue relates the above code, in this part of code, you should also configure it to write to the console.

Modify the code as below:

> .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration).WriteTo.Console())

Then, the output like this:

[image]